# Can the United States print as much as USD as needed to buy foreign goods and services?

Tags: united-states, usd-us-dollar, eur-euro

In my country now we facing big problem of lack of US dollars. As a country we print many local currency money and circulate them across country for local services such as paying salaries, Aids. but we can't use them to buy foreign services or goods.

My problem is, are countries like US not having that kind of problem? because many world services can buy for US Dollars and US can print as much as they want and pay for buy those services.

is it possible or not. if not why?

Comment: It comes down to the balance of trade. If your country starts selling things overseas, people will want to buy your local currency so they can buy the things your country sells! or they might just pay for the things in USD and then your country will have more USD. Either way your country wins.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is that US dollars are considered the world reserve currency at the moment. (That distinction has changed over history, typically every few hundred years.)

As such, they are effectively a standard where all other countries measure themselves against, it's widely used and accepted around the world, and different foreign countries hold reserves in USD to help stabilize their own currency.

On the other hand, a smaller national currency would only be accepted locally. It's value would be limited to the value of that nation's economy, and the only way to buy foreign goods would be to swap that money for the currency of the other country. To do that, you basically have to find someone who has that foreign currency and wants your national currency. Their willingness to do that trade is ultimately based on what they can buy in your country.

With USD as the reserve currency, there are many more people people around the world willing (and even preferring) to accept USD on top of just Americans, which helps stabilize the value even given unprecedented levels of new money being created.